# How to use alerts and prompts JS dialogs in Ruby on Rails implementation of Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

I'm learning Selenium now. I'm going to use it in the Ruby on Rails project. Now I created demo project just to test Selenium on Rails.

Content of #{RAILS_ROOT}/test/selenium/articles/delete_article.rsel is following:

```
setup :fixtures => :all

open "/articles"

assert_text_present("First Article title")
assert_text_present("Destroy")

click_and_wait("Destroy")
assert_match /Are you sure/i, get_confirmation

assert_text_present("Articles")
assert_text_not_present("First Article title")
```

During this test run I get following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `get_confirmation' for #<SeleniumOnRails::RSelenese::Evaluator
```

Other tests (without dialogs) are working without any problems.

Some info about configuration:

- ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel
  174) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 2.3.5
- Rubygems 1.3.5
- Selenium on Rails plugin (REVISION 38
  is last mentioned in the log
  CHANGELOG) from here http://svn.openqa.org/svn/selenium-on-rails/stable/selenium-on-rails
- No Remote Control. No installed gems
  related to selenium.
- Linux hsh
  2.6.31-17-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 10 17:01:44 UTC 2009 x86_64
  GNU/Linux
- Firefox 3.5.7

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
assert_alert /Are you sure/i
```

or this:

```
assert_confirmation /Are you sure/i
```

More in [SeleniumOnRails rdoc](http://svn.openqa.org/fisheye/browse/~raw,r=6/selenium-on-rails/trunk/doc/classes/SeleniumOnRails/TestBuilder.html)